# How to get data of filled orders in R using IBrokers?

Tags: r, quantitative-finance, algorithmic-trading, interactive-brokers, ibrokers

I am trying to fetch the performance of my historical trades. Does anyone know if there's a way to pull a similar table like what I have below, but for historical trade logs? Thanks!

```
> tws <- twsConnect()
> ac <- reqAccountUpdates(tws)
> position <- twsPortfolioValue(ac) ##current portfolio holdings
> position
    local sectype marketValue averageCost       return position realizedPNL unrealizedPNL
1     ABC     STK      xxxxx     xxxxxxx  -0.006855236        9           0         -4.52
2     USD    CASH     xxxxxxx    xxxxxxxx -0.004634901     3733           0        -23.19
```

Comment: No, you have to save them as they occur or use the statements from IB.  You can request executions for the current day in gateway or the last week in TWS by calling reqExecutions.

Comment: In case you don't know here is a link to flex statements.  https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/software/am/am/reports/using_the_flex_web_service.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
# This function will create 2 dataframes: one with account information, another with the live trades. You can always keep a log of the trades

IB.Account.Status <- function(tws, acctCode)
{
library(IBrokers)

cancelAccountUpdates(tws)
d <- reqAccountUpdates(conn = tws, acctCode, subscribe = TRUE)
assign("IB.account", data.frame(t(sapply(d[[1]],c)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE), envir = .GlobalEnv)

d2 <- d[[2]]
IB.contracts <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:length(d2))
{
 x <- bind_cols(data.frame(t(sapply(d2[[i]][1][[1]],c)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
 data.frame(t(sapply(d2[[i]][2][[1]],c)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE) )

IB.contracts <- bind_rows(IB.contracts, x)
rm(x, i)
}

IB.contracts <- IB.contracts[c("accountName", "conId", "symbol", "position", "marketPrice", "marketValue", "averageCost", "unrealizedPNL", "realizedPNL", "local", "currency", "exch", "primary", "sectype", "expiry", "strike", "right", "multiplier", "combo_legs_desc", "comboleg", "include_expired", "secIdType", "secId")]

cols.to.numeric <- c("strike", "right", "position", "marketPrice", "marketValue", "averageCost", "unrealizedPNL")

IB.contracts[cols.to.numeric] <- as.numeric(as.matrix(IB.contracts[cols.to.numeric]))

assign("IB.contracts", IB.contracts, envir = .GlobalEnv)
rm(d, d2, cols.to.numeric)

}
```